# I was wondering why there are multiple prefixes for the same meaning

Tags: prefixes, negative-prefixes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why “unequal” but “inequality”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15723/why-unequal-but-inequality)
>   [Origins of negative prefixes like in-, un-, il-, ir-, dis-, a-](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15725/origins-of-negative-prefixes-like-in-un-il-ir-dis-a)

There are a lot of prefixes for meaning "opposite". For example, *dis-, un-, in-*.

- *dissatisfied*
- *unstable*
- *incoherent*

I was wondering why there isn't just one prefix meaning "opposite" that could be used for all words. Is there a specific reason behind it? I found this link:

http://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/prefixes.htm

It sort of explains what each prefix means, but still *un-* and *in-* seem to have a lot in common. I am just wondering why have more than one.