# in-able ? un-able?

Tags: suffixes, prefixes, derivational-morphology, negative-prefixes, able-ible

Suffix -able adds meaning "being able" to a word. I know that.

Prefix in- and un- mean "not" or some negative meaning. I know that.

However, when it comes to mixing of these, I am confused.

- unbelievable
- indispensable

In the dictionary I can find many words of these forms, let's call them in-able and un-able, whose composing rule seems just random to me.

When given a certain word body, how can I make an in-able or un-able word to mean "not being able"?

Comment: I am unacquainted with any helpful rule, and I fear it is unknowable, although you may find this inconceivable. (Does that word mean what I think it means?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why “unequal” but “inequality”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15723/why-unequal-but-inequality) Read the [top and accepted answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/15724/300) there. Also, check out the questions linked from there, such as [Rule to determine when to use the prefix “im” vs. “un” to negate a word starting with “p”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33903/) and [I was wondering why there are multiple prefixes for the same meaning](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59247/)

Comment: So, net-net, you're looking for a "rule" that would enable the use of "un-able"?

Answer (score 11):

Consider *unbelievable* versus its synonym *incredible*, and you will find what there is to be found of an answer here.

The general tendency is to use *un‑* on Germanic words or any generic English term, and to use *in‑*  (possibly mutated; see next paragraph) for words of Latin origin.  This is not hard and fast, however; there are of course exceptions.

Also, the Latinate *in‑* prefix comes in other forms, like *illegible, immutable, irreducible*.  Those also count as *in‑* versions, not *un‑* versions.

Similarly, *‑able* is the more general ending, but *-ible* also frequently occurs. In fact, you will find that *‑able* and *‑ance* tend to go together, just as *‑ible* and *‑ence* tend to go together.

Here again there is an etymological explanation: whether it derived from either  a Germanic word or from a first-conjugation Latin verb (so Germanic words or Latin *‑are* verbs yield *‑able* type endings) on the one hand, or whether it was instead from another Latin conjugation (so *‑ere* verbs and such yield *‑ible* type endings) on the other.

But as before, there are notable exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a rule for that. Both preffixes `un-` and `in-` usually apply to adjectives, and that is what you get when you have something-able.

The only "rule" I can remember is that for some verbs, when you want to mean the reverse action, `un-` is what you want (*undo*, *unlock*, *untie*...).

Comment: No, there is a tendency, as @tchrist said; but it is not always reliable.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [elias](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/72130/77227) that there is no simple rule for this. Something that supports this viewpoint is that a number of words have shown variation over time, or still show variation: a famous example is "[inalienable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inalienable)" vs. "unalienable".

But it may be possible to give fairly accurate rules for certain subcategories of *-able* adjectives.

### If the *-able* word is based on a monosyllabic verb, use *un-.*

If you can remove the suffix *-able* from the adjective and get a monosyllabic English verb, the adjective almost certainly is negated with *un-* and not with *in-.*

I would guess that there are more than a hundred examples of words that follow this rule: to start with, you can consider *unthinkable, unspeakable,  unbearable, unstoppable, unflappable, unshakable, unforeseeable, unsalable, unquenchable, unbridgeable, unworkable, unlovable, unlikable, unwearable,  unbreakable, unchainable, unplayable, unwinnable.*

*Un-* is possible even when the verb is of French or Latin origin, as in *untouchable, untreatable, unusable, unnotable.*

I only know of four common exceptions to the monosyllable rule: *incurable* and *impassable* (for which the *un-* alternatives have negligible usage), *immovable* (which is much more common than *unmov(e)able*), and *insolvable* (which is currently less frequent than *unsolvable*). H. W. Fowler's *Modern English Usage* (first published 1926; republished 2009) mentions these four in a longer list of *in-_-able* words (*-able,* p. 5; for more information about Fowler's list, go to the next section).

*Insuitable* in place of *unsuitable* seems to be obsolete, although it can be found in dictionaries and some old documents.

### If the *-able* word is not based on a monosyllabic verb...

An *-able* adjective that is related to a verb of more than one syllable may take either *un-* or *in-* as the negative prefix: *un-* is generally more common and productive, but I don't know of any particularly simple rule that tells you which prefix to use for all words in this category. You can try to reason from the etymology, as described in tchrist's answer: an *-able* word built on a verb with Germanic etymology will take *un-* as a rule. The etymological criterion can be used to rule out *in-* for *unanswerable, unutterable, unforgettable.*

However, etymology usually can't be used to rule out *un-,* because *un-* is used with many *-able* words derived from Latin or French.

Fowler (1926, cited in the previous section) gives a list of around 100 *-able* words where he recommends forming the negative with *in-,* and says to use *un-* for any word not on his list.

#### Minor rules based on the spelling of the end of the word

- **If the word ends in *-kable*, use *un-.***

  I don't know of any exceptions to this in modern usage, but the words covered by it are mainly a subset of the words covered by the previous rule. We do also get *unremarkable, unmistakable, unrebukable, unattackable.* *Inattackable* seems to have once existed, but I think it's pretty much never used anymore.
- **If the word ends in *-cable*, you can use *in-.***

  There are words ending in *-cable* that can be negated by *un-* (e.g. *uneducable,* although apparently [some people prefer the sound of *ineducable*](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/ineducable-vs-uneducable.2736408/)).  But I haven't found any *-cable* adjectives that *cannot* be negated with *in-.*
- **If the word ends in *-yable*, use *un-.***

  As with *-kable,* most examples are monosyllables, but we also have *undestroyable, unemployable* and *unenjoyable.* *In-/im-* may be found in unassimilated French words that are occasionally used in English such as *[impayable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impayable), [incroyable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incroyable).*
- **If the word ends in *-onable*, use *un-.***

  There aren't so many words that end like this, but I think there are enough to identify this as a pattern. Many of these words end more specifically in *-ionable* or *-tionable.* Examples: *unquestionable, unexceptionable, unmentionable, unobjectionable; unconscionable, unfashionable; unseasonable, unreasonable,
  unpardonable.* "In-" is not always completely impossible in this context; "inconscionable" exists, but is much less common. "Infashionable" has been used occasionally in the past (it's in the OED), but is now obsolete.

Comment: There are some other exceptions to the monosyllabic rule, though they’re generally not synchronically based on anything recognisable within English: _inarable_, _incapable_, _ineffable_, _inscrutable_, _intractable_, _inviable_. Some are recognisable, though, like _insolvable_. (And who’s Elias? **Edit:** Oh, I see. The community wiki answer. The name of the poster of a CW answer doesn’t show up in the iOS app, apparently.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: elias wrote the community wiki answer to this question. I meant "a monosyllabic verb in English", although I should maybe edit to clarify: I don't think *are, cap(e), eff, scrute* and the like are used outside of jocular contexts.

Comment: Well, _eff_ is, but in a different sense. :-p _Solve_ definitely is, though, that’s an actual exception. (Apparently authors of CW answers don’t appear in the iOS app; never noticed that before.)