# pattern to predict -ent vs -ant?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, suffixes, ance-ence

Is there any pattern to predict whether to use **-ant** or **-ent**, in words such as those below?

abundant / attendant / arrogant **VS** abhorrent / absorbent / dependent

I find **-ent** seems to be more common... Some associate **-ant** with noun and **-ent** with adjective, but that does not always hold.

Comment: No good pattern. I read somewhere that a lot of these words had their spelling changed at some point in an inconsistent way. example: dependent/dependant

Comment: @sumelic The pattern used to be whether it derived from a non-(Latin first-conjugation) verb for *-ent/ence/ible*, and this is still more true than false, but yes, they changed several of them like *resistant* ≠ *persistent* (should both be *-ent*).

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/72133).

Comment: Similar to the `-er`/`-or` words, there is no good rule, though there are a few kind of general "tendencies" that have been observed.