# Derogatory term for inconcise writing

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, pejorative-language

I am looking for a derogatory word or short phrase to describe unconcise texts or the process of their creation, i.e., the text is redundant, overcomplicated and filled with irrelevant details or trivialities. The text is however not necessarily unstructured, entirely irrelevant or nonsensical.

The word should be applicable to written texts though it does not need to be restricted to them.

I expect such a term to exist, since German has many words for this *(labern, schwafeln, …)* – the suggested translations of which do not satisfy me, however, as they seem to be mainly about other negative aspects or spoken language or not derogatory.

Comment: There are many such words in English as well.  Rather than trying to pick one for you (because that's always just a battle for points), I'd suggest you look up synonyms for "***[prolix](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prolix)***", such as "verbose", "loquacious", etc (though some such words are typically applied only to speech, not writing).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Sorry if this is petty, but regarding the title - http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15725/origins-of-negative-prefixes-like-in-un-il-ir-dis-a/#59248

Comment: You could call it *verbal diarrhoea*. And if you don't mind mixing metaphors you could say it was a case of *verbal diarrhoea and mental constipation*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Pace* Dan Bron, the obvious word is ***waffle***:

> [mass noun] *British* Lengthy but vague or trivial talk or writing:
>   *we’ve edited out some of the waffle*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/waffle)

This may be related to the German *schwafeln,* I suppose. It fits your description of "redundant, overcomplicated and filled with irrelevant details or trivialities." There is a verb *waffle* as well, which means to produce waffle.

Comment: +1 for teaching me a neat new word (it's not used this way in the US; now I can out-pretentious my friends who imitate BrE!).

Comment: Note that in AmE, this word instead means to waver indecisively, so depending on your audience it might or might not be understood.

Answer (score 8):

One of possible words that come to mind is *[expatiate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expatiate)*:

> *to speak or write about something in a way that includes a lot of details or uses many words*
>
> The naturalist is known for her willingness to **expatiate** on any number of issues relating to wildlife and the environment.

*[Bloviate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bloviate)* may also be suitable:

> *to speak or write verbosely and windily*

(From Merriam-Webster)

Comment: I think bloviate carries the negative connotations the OP asked for.

Comment: Bloviate is good, but expatiate is both uncommon and not particularly negative.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like [rambling](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rambling) to me. While it's not explicit in the definition, culturally, rambling is typically seen as a derogatory statement of writings or speech.

> 1. aimlessly wandering.
> 2. taking an irregular course; straggling:
>      a rambling brook.
> 3. straying from one subject to another; desultory:
>      a rambling novel.
>
> The speaker rambled on with anecdote after anecdote.

It can also be used as a noun

> His journal was filled with incoherent ramblings.

Comment: *Rambling* was actually among the dissatisfactory translations I got as it seems to be mostly about a lack of good structure. The texts I am talking about are not necessarily badly structured or aimless; they are just overly verbose.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft - and "verbose" is insufficient? It generally has a negative context in English.

Comment: @Telastyn  I don't find verbose to be necessarily derogatory.

Answer (score 4):

I think "long-winded" applies.  If you want to damn it with faint praise, you can describe it as only "slightly topical" or "marginally germane."

A slightly longer phrase might be to "cram 2 pages of thoughts into 20 pages."  Also one can use "minutes" for speeches.

Comment: *Long-winded* is good, although it has connotations of speech rather than writing.  *Elliptical*, however, is the opposite of long-winded, it means that so much has been left out that the remainder is hard to understand.

Comment: That's certainly one meaning for elliptical, but I've also understood it to mean just plain obscure... though I'm willing to be re-educated.

Comment: *Elliptical* comes from *ellipsis*, to leave out words or phrases.  Webster defines it as "using few words and therefore hard to understand" and also as "marked by extreme economy of speech or writing."  It can definitely mean cryptic and indirect, but wordiness is a bit of an antonym.

Comment: [Webster's](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elliptical) also says " (2) :  of or relating to deliberate obscurity (as of literary or conversational style)"... but I'll concede the point.

Answer (score 3):

Try *wordy*, defined by google as "using or expressed in too many words."  It has the advantage of being the opposite of what it derides.

Answer (score 3):

Overly descriptive writing containing many flourishes, and redundant elements is also known as ***purple prose***.

Wikipedia says:

> In literary criticism, [purple prose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purple_prose) is written prose that is so
>   **extravagant**, **ornate**, or **flowery** as to break the flow and draw
>   excessive attention to itself. Purple prose is sensually evocative
>   beyond the requirements of its context.

An example of purple prose is the following

> **Plain**: He set the cup down.
>   **Middle Ground**: He eased the Big Gulp onto the table.
>   **ACK**: Without haste, the tall, blond man lowered the huge, plastic, gas station cup with a bright red straw onto the slick surface of the coffee table.

<sup>Source: [Write World](http://writeworld.org/post/39271116749/dont-be-a-dickens-avoiding-purple-prose) *Don't be a Dickens: Avoiding purple prose*</sup>

Comment: Some superb examples of wordiness writing here: http://www.bulwer-lytton.com/2013win.html (very amusing)

Comment: "Gaylord welcomed his Thanksgiving guests by unleashing a bullwar litany of throaty insults on his unsuspecting relatives, who had been patiently fidgeting as they awaited the arrival of the soup tureen with varying degrees of faked bonhomie".

Answer (score 1):

I despise **sloppy prose**. Be precise, be concise, or risk TLDNR.

**Poorly crafted** is also sometimes used for example: *Poorly crafted verbiage*.

In fact, **verbiage** alone is sometimes sufficient: [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/verbiage)

> a profusion of words usually of little or obscure content