# A word meaning <a short article or essay>

Tags: single-word-requests

I recently came across a word somewhere that literally meant:

> a short article or essay

It was most likely a loanword, either from Spanish or French. It began
with a *"C"* or a *"P"*, and was more than six letters long.

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196526/derogatory-term-for-inconcise-writing (I am teasing, but you should get the hint)

Comment: Yeah, I got the message, that my writing is tedious. But that's beside the point. And the "senior moment" was a sarcastic/ironic usage...well, as i have said before, and reiterate, that the word starts with either a "c" or a "p", and moderately outlandish [foreign sounding], yet part of the English language.

Comment: We need to start an EL&U Hall of Fame, and out this question in it.

Comment: @UniGuy precis, coup d'essai, clausula, disquisition??? I give up! ¦)

Comment: Nope. None of these. :-(

Comment: There's _codicil_ but that's more like an addition to an existing piece of work - especially legal stuff.

Comment: It *must* be [critique](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/critique) (she mutters...)

Comment: @Josh61 why did you delete your answer? At the very least it will stop users from repeating the same expressions.

Comment: For what it's worth, "compte rendu" doesn't fit, it means a report, a review, a statement, rather than an article. Plus it doesn't strike a chord.

Comment: *Vignette* might fit except for the first letter.

Comment: YOU JUST HIT THE SPOT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discovered in comments, the OP was looking for the word ***vignette***, and misremembered the first letter.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vignette) gives as definition 3a "a short descriptive literary sketch".

Comment: Yup, my bad! My memory's really clouded. *Sheepish* Thanks anyhow!

Comment: In my search, I found it also but didn't mention because it is totally different than what he is asking. It is usually used as an ornamental design. It has one meaning closer to what he is asking but not that close. It is a theatrical term.: "A brief verbal description of a person, place, etc.; a short descriptive or evocative episode in a play, etc." [OED]. But, well done for finding :)

Comment: It's a short piece of writing or an article, though not an essay. I messed up on the essay bit, i concur.

Comment: vignette
noun [C] UK /vɪˈnjet/
US
› a short piece of
writing, music,
acting, etc. which
clearly expresses the
typical
characteristics of
something or
someone:
"He wrote several
vignettes of small-
town life."
Source: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/vignette

Answer (score 4):

The word Cameo is not English sounding - it comes from the Old French and Italian.

[image]

> a short descriptive literary sketch that neatly encapsulates someone or something.

[Image and Definition -- Google Dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20cameo)

Comment: I'm gonna try skimming thru my dictionary. Let's hope for the best. Imma find that word if it's the last thing I do.

Comment: @Mari Very funny

Comment: @Mari, yeah, but now no one's going to get the jokes in the introduction to *my* answer.

Comment: @Dan cuz they deleted the word "middling"...sucks to you :-P :-P

Comment: And the word "Romance".

Answer (score 3):

Let's try ***pandect***; six letters (*about middling*), from a Romance language (Latin), and starts with a *p* (and bonus, contains a *c*):

> *A treatise or similar work that is comprehensive as to a particular topic.*

In other words,  just a more obscure way of spelling *monograph*.

Comment: The original **pandect** came from *Roman Law. A **compendium in fifty books** of Roman civil law, made by order of the emperor Justinian in the 6th cent., systematizing opinions of eminent jurists and given statutory force (OED)*, so it doesn't really work for OP's "short article or essay". Although **monographs** are usually equally *detailed*, they're often quite short because the subject matter is so tightly delineated - so +1 for that, even if it's not your primary suggestion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Monographs are not generally quite short—a monograph is simply a book that stands on its own, without being part of a journal or series. Many monographs are several hundreds or even thousands of pages long.

Answer (score 2):

Could you be thinking of *codicil*? While that is primarily used in legal contexts and means an *addendum*, it did originally mean "small book". The following definition is from *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition* by way of [wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/codicil):

> *codicil*
>
> n. Law A supplement or appendix to a will.
>
> n. A supplement or appendix.

[Etymonlne](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=codicil&allowed_in_frame=0) gives the origin of the word as

> codicil (n.)
>       early 15c., from Middle French codicille, from Latin codicillus "a short writing, a small writing tablet," diminutive of codex (genitive codicis), see code (n.).

I don't have access to an unabridged OED at the moment but I suspect that the word can/could also be used to mean *short text* in English at some point.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not codicil, man...thanks for trying though :-) I'm bound to hit upon it sooner or later.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider these terms:

- *Prolusion* — A literary essay or article intended as a precursor to a fuller treatment of a subject. [[OED]](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/152395?redirectedFrom=prolusion#eid) - From *Latin*
- *Precede* — Brief editorial preface (usually to an article or essay) [[Wiktionary]](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/precede) - From *Old French* and *Latin*
- *Conte* — A short story as a form of literary composition. [[OD]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/conte#cont%C3%A9) - From *French* and *Latin*

Comment: Some other distant candidates: _epitome_,_compendium_,_conspectus_,_apercu_,_feuilleton_,_passage_

Answer (score 1):

Morceau could be the word? It doesn't sound english:

> A short literary or musical composition.

-- [Google Dictionary](http://www.google.com/search?q=define%20morceau)

Answer (score 1):

**[Causerie](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/causerie)**

*Noun*. French origin.

An informal talk or chat.
A short informal essay or article.

Comment: I'd already specially written in my original post, before it was censored, that the word wasn't "causerie".

Comment: @Uni Guy Bugger, I've just seen the comment where you say it isn't causerie. Oh well in that case I truly give up! A pox on your infernal question sir! ¦Þ

Comment: Lol. It ain't infernal. I'll come by the answer one of these days, and then you'll know what you'd been missing. Nice try, though   :-P

Answer (score 0):

He wrote a *piece* on tiny houses.